# How to access array index of API call response dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, fetch-api

I am using the Yelp API to return a list of businesses, the response is an object that has a key called "businesses" the value for this key is an array of 20 items those items are objects, but I am not sure how to access each item in the array without hard coding it like array[0] I would like to use a variable to access the index of the array dynamically so I won't have to input 0,1 etc and I'd be able to input the index needed to get the id or location for every item within this array here's an example `business[vartoaccesseachindex].id`. The reason for this is because I am using a .map() function to return a new array of objects with the values I need from the response.

Here is the object from the response

```
…}
​
businesses: (20) […]
​​
0: Object { id: "uJZgom8HpK74xz8IojpT0A", alias: "pizzeria-beddia-philadelphia", name: "Pizzeria Beddia", … }
​​
1: Object { id: "M_EpyAH1CZZVlhxfYBLOqg", alias: "nomad-pizza-company-philadelphia", name: "Nomad Pizza Company", … }
​​
2: Object { id: "wuH4TPUo8oJo4E59xZKsNg", alias: "and-pizza-philadelphia", name: "&pizza", … }
​​
3: Object { id: "VSDdUwXktnvL_O0meKv7MQ", alias: "alice-pizza-philadelphia", name: "Alice Pizza", … }
​​
4: Object { id: "jyBbsc6LrIwdJYD9jFuiaw", alias: "aldo-and-manny-pizza-and-pasta-philadelphia", name: "Aldo and Manny Pizza and Pasta", … }
​​
5: Object { id: "cFSyJluKa2SHtgMMvlx6SQ", alias: "angelos-pizzeria-philadelphia", name: "Angelo's Pizzeria", … }
​​
6: Object { id: "jNxvJeAUzzpC7zW3UN78HA", alias: "pizza-shackamaxon-philadelphia", name: "Pizza Shackamaxon", … }
​​
7: Object { id: "4PyqPHAiFopyZZlLcLQuVg", alias: "d-oliva-evoo-pizza-and-grill-philadelphia", name: "D'Oliva evoo Pizza & Grill", … }
​​
8: Object { id: "0-JRAY0LpBazDuA9761U5w", alias: "pizzeria-vetri-philadelphia-6", name: "Pizzeria Vetri", … }
​​
9: Object { id: "IzyQVIJG8JAnOiRQPb0-wg", alias: "rione-philadelphia", name: "Rione", … }
​​
10: Object { id: "7pwZZVVlYCxQvVdd8Q03wg", alias: "la-rosa-pizzeria-philadelphia", name: "La Rosa Pizzeria", … }
​​
11: Object { id: "u7_3L1NBWgxhBM_B-cmmnA", alias: "pizzeria-vetri-philadelphia-5", name: "Pizzeria Vetri", … }
​​
12: Object { id: "bmJgvpuf2GBXd62ELK0Q2w", alias: "luigis-pizza-fresca-philadelphia", name: "Luigi's Pizza Fresca", … }
​​
13: Object { id: "5Fm6khB-De-OdqATep9J9Q", alias: "nypd-pizza-philadelphia", name: "NYPD Pizza", … }
​​
14: Object { id: "Mna6U7kUX36l8-dpDt-U-A", alias: "gianfranco-pizza-rustica-philadelphia", name: "Gianfranco Pizza Rustica", … }
​​
15: Object { id: "TKPAyOWcexkpVHPCdYTNmQ", alias: "spuntino-wood-fired-pizza-philadelphia", name: "Spuntino Wood Fired Pizza", … }
​​
16: Object { id: "sL6fC0P4C-gyL4E5gacUeQ", alias: "lazaros-pizzeria-and-grill-philadelphia-2", name: "Lazaro's Pizzeria & Grill", … }
​​
17: Object { id: "I1H5s9cVCGh1nH-4bhsSDA", alias: "santuccis-original-square-pizza-philadelphia-2", name: "Santucci's Original Square Pizza", … }
​​
18: Object { id: "6ajnOk0GcY9xbb5Ocaw8Gw", alias: "barbuzzo-philadelphia", name: "Barbuzzo", … }
​​
19: Object { id: "vC98a0bIcSDVfX3dOuuAkQ", alias: "yummy-pizza-philadelphia", name: "Yummy Pizza", … }
```

Here is my JS code this is the .map()function to return a new object with extracted info. The info extracted would be sotored in a key/value pair, so id would have to get access to business[vartoaccesseachindex]id, imageSrc would have to access business[vartoaccesseachindex].imageSrc.

```
jsonResponse.businesses.map( business => {
            return {
                id: business[vartoaccesseachindex],
                imageSrc: business,
                name: business,
                address:  business,
                city: business,
                state:  business,
                zipCode:  business,
                category: business,
                rating: business,
                reviewCount:  business,
            }
          });
```

Any answers are greatly appriceated.

Comment: you already have the object 'business'. access it directly 'business.id' ....

Comment: If I try that it comes up undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `map` callback is already supplied the object you need.  If you really need the index, it is supplied as a second parameter.

```js
const jsonResponse = {
  more: {stuff: 'here'},
  businesses: [
    { id: "uJZgom8HpK74xz8IojpT0A", alias: "pizzeria-beddia-philadelphia", name: "Pizzeria Beddia"},
    { id: "M_EpyAH1CZZVlhxfYBLOqg", alias: "nomad-pizza-company-philadelphia", name: "Nomad Pizza Company"},
    { id: "wuH4TPUo8oJo4E59xZKsNg", alias: "and-pizza-philadelphia", name: "&pizza"},
    // ... 
  ]
}

const myData = jsonResponse .businesses .map ( (business, index) => ({
  id: business.id,
  index: index,
  name: business.name,
  // ... 
}))

console .log (
  myData
)
```

My question, though, is whether you're copying the entire object with your list of properties.  And if so, why bother?  Why not just use the `business` objects available in your array?

Comment: Thank you I was looking at my code incorrectly, I was trying to look at the object outside of the .map function. Also, I'm not copying the entire object just the snippets from the object I need.